# Want to git checkout tag, but no files?

Tags: git, tags, checkout

I can do: git checkout tags/v1.0 but where's the files? git log shows it worked, but I need the files. My current subdirectory is not populated with tagged files; how do you get the tagged version of files?

Real example: clone the git repo, then check a given tag:

```
git clone https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git
git tag --list
git checkout v4.3.0
```

That's what html5-boilerplate.git advises, and I understand that part. I can checkout a given annotated tagged version, but how do I pull the files out, so that I can actually review the code in the current subdirectory? Do I need to do something like rebasing to pull the files into the current subdirectory somehow? I'm missing the basic technique, and I can't seem to find help on this question elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show us the commands you used and their output?

Comment: Try `git checkout v1.0`

Comment: I clone the repo you mentioned. using
git clone https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git
And checkout the version using
git checkout v7.1.0
It works. If the files are there in that version, you should see it

Comment: After you've cloned, unless you did a `--bare` clone (for some reason, but I guess not), you should have a working tree (directories and files described in the HEAD commit), typically where your `.git` directory is. Do you have one?

Comment: Thanks, I modified my question to be more clear. I do know how to checkout a tag from a cloned repository, but how do I get the files out of git then? "git log" shows me I've got the version I want. So, I want the files...that's the whole idea of git. I want the tagged version of the project...I need the actual files at that snapshot.

Comment: By default, your working tree root is set next to the root `.git` dir, where you did your `git init`

Comment: Based on what you said, you have already checked out all the files. If the files are not there, they are really not there. There is no "pull the file out" operation for git. If you clone the repository, you have already cloned all the "snapshots" and "files" in that repository.

Comment: Yeah, it's working!  I had thought the files didn't change, but they did.  It was late at night...thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I clone the repo you mentioned, using

```
git clone github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git
```

And checkout the version using

```
git checkout v7.1.0
```

It works. If the files are there in that version, you should see it.

Based on what you said, you have already checked out all the files. If the files are not there, they are really not there. There is no "pull the file out" operation for git. If you clone the repository, you have already cloned all the "snapshots" and "files" in that repository.